# как в vscode сделать светящиеся буквы?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Я видел у одного зарубежного стримера в vscode ( Visual Studio Code ), буквы, как будто они сияли. То есть есть подсветка синтаксиса, а есть ещё такое, что они как будто светятся.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Есть тема для VScode "Neon" установить её  можно через package control**

Answer (score 0):

Ну это решается установкой [темы для VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RobbOwen.synthwave-vscode)

Answer (score -1):

Эту тему можете найти по названию - SynthWave '84.
Ну и оставлю [ссылку на неё](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RobbOwen.synthwave-vscode), там сможете найти как включить свечение у данной темы.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: ссылка, кстати, повторяет уже приведённую в [соседнем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1074980/178576), так что ваш ответ, без дополнительной информации, фактически не привносит ничего нового. // чтобы дополнить ответ, нажмите [edit]

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).